# How to rename multiple columns in multiple files?

Tags: r, bash, awk, sed

I have multiple files which look like this:

```
trans_ENSG00000047849.txt.traw
trans_ENSG00000047848.txt.traw
trans_ENSG00000047847.txt.traw
...
```

In them I have around 300 columns, and column names look like this:

```
NA20826_NA20826 NA20828_NA20828 NA20819_NA20819
```

I would like that my column names in all files have instead this form:

```
NA20826 NA20828 NA20819
```

In other words I would like to remove everything after underscore _ in every column name and in every file.

I should mention that there is a here is a tab space at the beginning of each file.

I tried this:

```
sed -ri 's/[_].*$//' trans_*.txt.traw
```

but when I tried to open one of these transformed files in R I got this error:

```
> e=read.table("trans_ENSG00000135541.txt.traw", header=TRUE)
Error in read.table("trans_ENSG00000135541.txt.traw", header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names
```

Comment: Try `sed -ri 's/\<([A-Za-z0-9]+)_\1\>/\1/g'  trans_*.txt.traw`. See https://ideone.com/9Ibqp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you actually want this:

```
$ echo -e "\tNA20826_NA20826\tNA20828_NA20828\tNA20819_NA20819" | sed -r '1s/_[^\t]*//g'
        NA20826 NA20828 NA20819
```

`_[^\t]*` since it's `TAB` separated, so starting from `_` to before the `TAB` (or end of line) are things to be deleted.
`g` flag is to replace all occurances in line.
The first `1` is to limit the replace in first line -- The title line.

Your own **s**ubstitude command `'s/[_].*$//'`, is to replace from the first `_` to the end of the line, so it will ends up with only one title left.

Comment: amazing and incredibly helpful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Sed command you need is:

```
sed -ri 's/_\S*//g'
```

This regexp removes part of every word, starting from underline until next space or tab character, no matter how many columns has each line.